# git alias for branch point for rebasing purposes

Tags: git

I'm wondering if there is a git alias for the commit for where you branch from. I often use this to rebase and pretty up my commits before creating a MR/PR.

Work flow:

```
        -- F -- G -- H
      /
A -- B -- C -- D -- E
```

In the example above, I'm working on feature branch which I'm intending to merge back at a later point (`F-G-H`). What I often do while working is rebasing against the branch point (`B`), and making sure that my commits looks good (e.g. squashing `H` into `F`).

Is there an alias for `B` in this case. Today I'm repeatedly looking up the commit hash to achieve this, a kind of `git rebase -i branch-point`.

I know I can rebase against the main branch (or originating branch), but some times there are merge issues I don't want to deal with then and there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no alias.... it's something you can calculate, though

```
git merge-base H E
```

And if you intend to squash into a single commit you can do

```
git reset --soft $( git merge-base H E )
git commit -m "There, a single commit"
```

Comment: It occurs to me that you could alias that pair of commands; the alias would need one parameter, the name of the other branch.

Comment: Or you could check the value of `@{u}`, I think (if there is one, of course).

Answer (score 0):

There are no aliases for it unless you create them. But, you can create an alias, by creating a tag. Before reading on, take a look here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

You can list your tags like

```
git tag
```

and you can search for them like

```
git tag -l "v1.8.5*"
```

You can also annotate your tags, like

```
git tag -a v1.4 -m "my version 1.4"
```

So, something like this would be useful:

```
git tag -a somebranch-creation -m "branched out somebranch"
git branch somebranch
git checkout somebranch
git push -u origin somebranch
```

Since the branch name varies and you want to reuse this, make it a bash script or something, receive the name of the new branch as a parameter and inject it into all the places where you see **somebranch** above.

Answer (score 0):

In a topology like this

```
        -- F -- G -- H <- me
      /
A -- B -- C -- D -- E <- main
```

... Git has no knowledge, when you are on `me`, that `main` even exists, or that `B` is somehow special. All Git sees is that `me` is `H` plus the parent chain from there, `H G F B A`. Thus it is impossible to specify `B` without doing one of the following:

- Giving the SHA of B.
- Giving the count of B back thru the parent chain.
- Giving the name of the "other branch" (`main` in this case).

What I do in real life count. `B` is three before `H`:

```
git reset --soft @~3
```

I do have an alias for that: I call it `git back n` where `n` is the number of steps to go back along the parent chain (3 in this case):

```
back = "!f() { git reset --soft @~${1} ; }; f"
```

I have a frequent dance I do:

```
git branch temp # just in case
git back 3      # or whatever
git commit      # to squash; or omit this and just keep working
```

The idea is that I can add to what I've done, or change what I've done, or just commit as is, and no matter what, I've got a way to get back to where I was in case of need — that's what the extra `temp` branch is for, as a bookmark.